# Shibboleth Authentication to AD failed with error "file not found"

Tags: ldap, authentication, shibboleth

I am new to Shibboleth and try to configure authentication between ADFS and Shibboleth. The users are stored in AD.
I've already connected ADFS and Shibboleth and able to see the login page, after submitting username and credentials I am getting an error "authentication failed".

The logs shows following error:

> 16:46:06.929 - DEBUG
>   [edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.authn.provider.UsernamePasswordLoginServlet:177]
>   - User authentication for cc failed java.lang.SecurityException: Configuration Error:     No such file or directory   at
>   com.sun.security.auth.login.ConfigFile.(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_45]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_45]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_45]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]

I am not able to find out which file is missing and where I've made the mistake. 
Any help highly appreciated.

login.config looks as followed:

```
ShibUserPassAuth {

// Example LDAP authentication
// See: https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/SHIB2/IdPAuthUserPass

   edu.vt.middleware.ldap.jaas.LdapLoginModule required
      host="idmgt-IP0.idmgtext.demo"
      port="389"
      base="CN=Users,DC=idmgtext,DC=demo"
      serviceCredential="Corp123!"
      userRoleAttribute="sAMAccountName"
      serviceUser="ShibolethService@idmgtext.demo"
      subtreeSearch = "true"
      ssl="false"
      userFilter="sAMAccountName={0}";

// Example Kerberos authentication, requires Sun's JVM
// See: https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/SHIB2/IdPAuthUserPass
/*
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
      useKeyTab="true"
      keyTab="/path/to/idp/keytab/file";
*/

};
```

handler.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ProfileHandlerGroup xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:idp:profile-handler"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:idp:profile-handler classpath:/schema/shibboleth-2.0-idp-profile-handler.xsd">

    <!-- Error Handler -->
    <ErrorHandler xsi:type="JSPErrorHandler" jspPagePath="/error.jsp" />

    <!-- Profile Handlers -->
    <!-- 
        All profile handlers defined below are accessed via the Servlet path "/profile" so if your profile 
        handler's request path is "/Status" then the full path is "<servletContextName>/profile/Status"
     -->
    <ProfileHandler xsi:type="Status">
        <RequestPath>/Status</RequestPath>
    </ProfileHandler>

    <ProfileHandler xsi:type="SAMLMetadata" metadataFile="C:\opt\Shib2Idp/metadata/idp-metadata.xml">
        <RequestPath>/Metadata/SAML</RequestPath>
    </ProfileHandler>    

    <ProfileHandler xsi:type="ShibbolethSSO"
                    inboundBinding="urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:profiles:AuthnRequest"
                    outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:browser-post 
                                                urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:artifact-01">
        <RequestPath>/Shibboleth/SSO</RequestPath>
    </ProfileHandler>

    <ProfileHandler xsi:type="SAML1AttributeQuery" 
                    inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:bindings:SOAP-binding"
                    outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:bindings:SOAP-binding">
        <RequestPath>/SAML1/SOAP/AttributeQuery</RequestPath>
    </ProfileHandler>

    <ProfileHandler xsi:type="SAML1ArtifactResolution" 
                    inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:bindings:SOAP-binding"
                    outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:bindings:SOAP-binding">
        <RequestPath>/SAML1/SOAP/ArtifactResolution</RequestPath>
    </ProfileHandler>

    <ProfileHandler xsi:type="SAML2SSO" 
                    inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                    outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign
                                                urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST 
                                                urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact">
        <RequestPath>/SAML2/POST/SSO</RequestPath>
    </ProfileHandler>

    <ProfileHandler xsi:type="SAML2SSO" 
                    inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign"
                    outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign
                                                urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST 
                                                urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact">
        <RequestPath>/SAML2/POST-SimpleSign/SSO</RequestPath>
    </ProfileHandler>

    <ProfileHandler xsi:type="SAML2SSO" 
                    inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
                    outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign
                                                urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST 
                                                urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact">
        <RequestPath>/SAML2/Redirect/SSO</RequestPath>
    </ProfileHandler>

    <ProfileHandler xsi:type="SAML2AttributeQuery"
                    inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
                    outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP">
        <RequestPath>/SAML2/SOAP/AttributeQuery</RequestPath>
    </ProfileHandler>

    <ProfileHandler xsi:type="SAML2ArtifactResolution" 
                    inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
                    outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP">
        <RequestPath>/SAML2/SOAP/ArtifactResolution</RequestPath>
    </ProfileHandler>

    <!-- Login Handlers
    <LoginHandler xsi:type="RemoteUser">
        <AuthenticationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</AuthenticationMethod>
    </LoginHandler>
     -->
    <!--  Username/password login handler -->
    <LoginHandler xsi:type="UsernamePassword" 
                  jaasConfigurationLocation="file://C:\opt\Shib2Idp/conf/login.config">
        <AuthenticationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</AuthenticationMethod>        
    </LoginHandler>

    <!-- 
        Removal of this login handler will disable SSO support, that is it will require the user to authenticate 
        on every request.
    -->
    <LoginHandler xsi:type="PreviousSession">
        <AuthenticationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PreviousSession</AuthenticationMethod>
    </LoginHandler>

</ProfileHandlerGroup>
```